# Keep Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and Cannot Determine Why

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexing

Working on a program that will read input from a file (using the Declaration of Independence as a test) and write the number of ints, chars, strings, etc. into another new file. But I'm running into a problem with my array index being out of bounds. I've looked over my loops a dozen times now, but I can't figure out what could be causing the problem. Thanks in advance for any help =]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P5 {

    static String arrayString[] = new String[100];
    static int numberLines = 0;
    static int numberWords = 0;
    static int numberChars = 0;
    static int numberUpper = 0;
    static int numberLower = 0;
    static int numberDigits = 0;
    static int numSpaces = 0;
    static int numberTabs = 0;
    static int numberSpecial = 0;


    private static void readFile(String inputFile) {    
        try{

            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("Declaration.txt"));

            while(fileScan.hasNext()){

                arrayString[numberWords] = fileScan.next();
                numberWords++;
            }

            while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
                numberLines++;
            }

            fileScan.close();
        }

        catch(IOException e){
        }
    }   

    private static void gatherStatistics(String sArray[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++){

            String line = sArray[i];
            numberChars += line.length();

            for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++){

                char c = line.charAt(j);    

                if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
                    numberUpper++;

                else if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
                    numberLower++;

                else if(Character.isDigit(c))
                    numberDigits++;

                else if(Character.isSpaceChar(c))
                    numSpaces++;

                else if(c == '\t')
                    numberTabs++;

                else
                    numberSpecial++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeFile(String outputFile) {

        try{

            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new File("Statistics.txt"));
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberLines);
            fileOut.println("Number of Words: " + numberWords);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberChars);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberUpper);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberLower);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberDigits);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numSpaces);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberTabs);
            fileOut.println("Number of Lines: " + numberSpecial);

            fileOut.close();
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readFile(args[0]);
        gatherStatistics(arrayString);
        writeFile(args[1]);
        System.exit(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (FileNotFoundException e){}` never have an empty catch block. Which line is throwing your AIOOBE?

Comment: Sure, here's the exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at P5.readFile(P5.java:34)
 at P5.main(P5.java:103)

Comment: Which line is 34 of P5.java?

Comment: Is your file have line more than 100?

Comment: How many lines are in `"Declaration.txt"`?

Comment: Line 34 is:     arrayString[numberWords] = fileScan.next();

Comment: so you have more than 100 words?

Comment: why do you set the array limit to 100 ? the error is quite self-explained.

Comment: Yep. You should be using an `ArrayList<String>`, not an array.

Comment: Believe I may have figured out the issue. I was using fileScan.next() instead of fileScan.nextLine() to input values into the array. Changing it to while(fileScan.hasNext()){

    numberWords++;
   }

   while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
    arrayString[numberLines] = fileScan.next();
    numberLines++;
   } has stopped the problem. Now I just need to figure out what's causing an infinite loop hehe.

Comment: Which infinite loop?  Have you tried using your debugger to debug your program?

Comment: In an introduction to Java class, and I'm following my notes which directed me to set the array limit to 100 for this program. We also haven't gone over debugging yet. I think that it's the topic for this week. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

You have read a file with more than 100 lines.

Instead of using array, use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Change this line:

```
static String arrayString[] = new String[100];
```

to:

```
static ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Change this line:

```
private static void gatherStatistics(String sArray[]) {
```

to:

```
private static void gatherStatistics(ArrayList<String> sArray) {
```

Change this line:

```
arrayString[numberWords] = fileScan.next();
```

to

```
arrayString.add(fileScan.next());
```